# Analyzing with SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild on Windows 10

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Two weeks ago I was able to run and analyse .net projects on windows 10 but after some times, it stopped. I am getting this app can't run on your PC , To find the version for your PC, Check with the software publisher.
I was following this url [Scanning using Ms Build](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Scanning+on+Windows)
I have also changed my local security option, the option of allow UIAccess applications to prompt for elevation without using the secure desktop to Enabled.
I am using windows 10.0.16299 x64 and there is no recent updates done on the computer.

I am running the command from sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.0.2.892\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe and I have sonarqube-7 installed and running.

What Am I missing, I am not sure what caused the execution to stop and I checked there is no antivirus or firewall blocking and there is no error .

Comment: A wild guess: When you downloaded the zip, did you unblock the zip first before unzipping?

Comment: Sonar has released a new scanner for .net and .netcore and these have fixed my issue